# Comparing files in folder and moving them if size smaller

Tags: c#, file, vba, batch-file, compare

im new here, have been trying to compere one file to another and if previous file in folder is bigger then move the file. I was trying to find solution for vba, batch, c# but had no luck yet. there are many files in folder sorted by date and we need to compare one file to next and so on. If i could get ANY help on that i would greatly appreciate that!

Comment: In c#, [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) will give you the files size

Comment: Please provide examples. What do you mean by "previous file?" Move which file where?

Comment: Native Batch math is restricted to files less than 2 GB.  Are all your files less than this size?

Comment: in batch, `forfiles` /? will give you the filesize

Answer (score 0):

For c#:

- Use the static methods on the Directory class to get a list of the files in a folder.
- Use the FileInfo class to get information about the files (IE: file size)
- Use File.Move() to relocate the files if they match your criteria.

Have a look over the [IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx) and [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) documentation to see all the bad things that might happen when your program runs.